# how to print max size of list inside a list

Tags: python

For example:

```
alist=[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0), (1, 0), (3, 0)], 
[(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3)],
[(0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6)],
[(1, 5)],
[(2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (2, 5), (3, 2), (3, 1)]]

for i in dlist:
    print(len(i))
    print(max(len(i)))  #this gives me error
```

output:

```
5
9
3
8
1
7
```

I wanted to print out 9 as my output from the above list. How am I able to print the result?

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat more terse

```
len(max(alist,key=len))
```

Comment: This also works. If you don't need an intermediary form (mine generates the lengths of each sublist, this finds the actual longest sublist) I don't see much to choose between them.

Comment: Actually, some profiling shows this to be about twice as fast as my version. Neither are exactly slow.

Answer (score 3):

If you can be sure your nesting is only one level (that is, a list of lists):

```
print max(len(sublist) for sublist in alist)
```

Answer (score 1):

functional style using map:

```
print max(map(len, alist))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the actual index of the longest sublist:

```
max(((i,l) for i,l in enumerate(alist)), key=lambda t: len(t[1]))[0]
```

Or, as stated in comments:

```
max(enumerate(alist), key=lambda t: len(t[1]))[0]
```

Comment: `max(enumerate(alist), key=lambda t: len(t[1]))[0]` works just as well

Comment: @1_CR: Aren't you terse today! ;-) Yes that is better still.

Comment: or try this on for size `alist.index(max(alist,key=len))` ;-)